# How to post within a rvest html_session?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

How can i post "within" a html session?

So after i opened a session via `a <- rvest::html_session(url)`

I tried:

```
library(httr)
POST(path, 
          add_headers(setNames(as.character(headers(a)), names(headers(a)))), 
          set_cookies(setNames(cookies(a)$value, cookies(a)$name)),
          body = list(...), 
          encode = "json")
```

But this handles my request as I were not logged in. Any suggestions?
I am looking for something like `POST(session, path, body, ...)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, after some digging into it i solved it by using:

```
x %>% rvest:::request_POST(url,
          config(referer = x$url),
          user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36"),
          body = list(...), 
          encode = "form")
```

Where `rvest:::request_POST` internally uses

```
httr::POST(url, x$config, ..., handle = x$handle)
```

Comment: This brilliant trick also helped me [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327657/).

Comment: @Rentrop: This request_POST method is now deprecated entirely in RVEST. What should be done in that case?